# Javascript inject value into css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to alter background color via a value added into our EMM software.
If I fill in the specific field currently I can output that text on the screen, this works fine, but now I want to use that to inject that value into CSS.

Parts of the coding I have so far is as follows:

```
html,
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="Background">
  </div>
```

```
HTMLbackground = "";
```

```
case "BACKGROUND":
  if (SotiDispImg[index] === "") {
      HTMLbackground = "<span class=\"Title\">" + SotiDisp[index] + "</span>";
  }
```

```
document.getElementById("Background").innerHTML = HTMLbackground;
```

With this HTMLbackground would be any value I fill into the software field (i.e #000000)
But now I would like to inject HTMLbackground in html,body background:
I just have no idea at the moment how to go about this.

Does anyone have any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: Use a CSS variable in your stylesheet, and then set the value for that via JS - details, see duplicate.

Comment: Like this --- HTML: `<div id="target" class="container">I've changed!</div>` CSS: `.pink { background-color: pink; }` JS: `const TARGET_ELEMENT = document.querySelector('#target'); if (TARGET_ELEMENT) { TARGET_ELEMENT.classList.add('pink')}`